# Use js plugin from node modules in vuejs

Tags: import, vue.js, vue-component, node-modules

How can import cal-heatmap(https://www.npmjs.com/package/cal-heatmap) to my project after saving it with npm install?

I tried to use it like this:

```
<script>
import calHeatmap from 'cal-heatmap'

    export default { 
    name: 'heatmap',
    props: {
         inspection: Object
    },
    data () {
       return {
           current: new Date().getFullYear()
       }
    },
    beforeMount () {
       var cal = new CalHeatMap()
       cal.init({})
    }
   }
  </script>
```

And I get that CalHeatMap() is not defined.

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: No, it was intalled succesfully. However I am new to javascript programming. Should I import it directly to my component like this: import calheatmap from '../node_modules/cal-heatmap/cal-heatmap.js'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write it like this directly in the component:

```
import CalHeatmap from 'cal-heatmap'
```

Comment: I just uptade the question with my code, the console says that CalHeatMap() is not defined.

Comment: @user2766512 CalHeatmap's first letter should be C

Comment: @user2766512 just like this : important CalHeatmap from 'cal-heatmap'

Answer (score 0):

```
import CalHeatMap from 'cal-heatmap
```

is right

besides, remember to import css file

```
import 'cal-heatmap/cal-heatmap.css'
```